# Encrypt/decrypt using C#, data encrypted using Ruby on Rails Lockbox

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, encryption

I'm converting a system made in Ruby on Rails to C# .NET 6 and I'm not able to understand how encryption is done using Rails Lockbox.

To contextualize, in Ruby on Rails there is a gem called Lockbox that automatically, from a key, encrypts and decrypts data from a column in the database.
Example:

```
class ExternalStore < ApplicationRecord
  enum store_type: { shopify: 0 }

  # Encrypted fields
  encrypts :api_key, :api_password
...
```

In C# I tried to use some libraries to do this like
*Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DataEncryption* and *EntityFrameworkCore.EncryptColumn*, but still no success. Attempts to do it by hand were also unsuccessful.

For testing purposes:

- **Lockbox encryption key:** 8ea779ed903113c0981a9224f5f4a41f220102c3b9ff160472ebff31f2d68ff6
- **Original text:** 8d7761fcca8de2fb135ab80aec02a811
- **Ciphertext:** 1XT+UUPptMhqDO7AG+UwKk35y3eSrCbxlOUz9H0g9T9xo1Dnlg7xNEJH76z0iS4kwIBStZvF4ZW60T9v

I would really appreciate if someone showed me how to do this.
Thanks.

Below are some links I used to try:

- [Lockbox git](https://github.com/ankane/lockbox)
- [Lockbox readme](https://github.com/ankane/lockbox/blob/dd3384dd63a883f605f71606f29c7293f73526d7/lib/lockbox/key_generator.rb#L2)
- [DataEncription](https://github.com/Eastrall/EntityFrameworkCore.DataEncryption)
- [ColumnEncryption](https://github.com/emrekizildas/EntityFrameworkCore.EncryptColumn)

PS: Sorry for bad english

Comment: Looks like Lockbox uses HKDF with SHA384 under the covers. Also looks like it uses a salt which is the table name. There is an HKDF class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hkdf?view=net-6.0) in the .NET framework, and of course a SHA384 class. That's where I'd start -- using them to replicate the lockbox implementation.

Comment: Looks like AES-256 in GCM mode, the ciphertext is the concatenation of 12 bytes nonce, actual ciphertext and 16 bytes tag, in that order, s. [Compatibility](https://github.com/ankane/lockbox/blob/master/docs/Compatibility.md). However, the posted ciphertext cannot be decrypted with the posted key in this way. Are you sure that the test data (key, ciphertext, plaintext) is valid/consistent?

Comment: Actually the test data I was told was wrong, now it is correct. Testing with these keys in Rails console itself worked the decryption, but I still couldn't reproduce it in C#.

Comment: Only one thing this lockbox key that I informed is the master_key, I don't know if there's a difference.